# ul is null のエラー表示を解決するには<todolistの作成＞

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, ecmascript-6

ATOMを用いてtodolistの作成を行っています。（youtube "JavaScriptの「基礎」が1時間で分かる「超」入門講座【初心者向け】-  だれでもエンジニア / 山浦清透"　に沿って行っています。）
フォーム欄に入力したものをリスト化して表示する段階でulとliの紐づけを行ったのですがul is nullというエラー表示がされフォームに入力した文字がリスト化されません。実際のコードがこちらです。youtubeにおいてもHTMLのulは空欄になっていました。また、この方はconstを用いていますがES6に関するエラー表示からvarを用いています。
よろしくお願いします。

```
*index.html*
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ToDo List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h1>ToDo List</h1>
    <style>
            h1{text-align:center; color:rgba(195, 64, 16, 0.83); font-family:fantasy; font-size:80px;}
    </style>
    <form id="form" name="form">
        <input id="input" placeholder="Things to do" type="text">
    </form>
    <style>
              #form{text-align: center;}
    </style>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
    <ul class="list-group text-secondary" id="ul"></ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

*index.js*
var form = document.getElementById("form");
var input = document.getElementById("input");
var ul = document.getElementById("ul");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    add();
});
function add() {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerText = input.value;
    li.classList.add("list-group-item");
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";
}
```

Comment: コードは画像ではなくテキストとして質問文に入れてください。コードの質問とAtomの質問は関係がないので分けてください。

Comment: ごありがとうございます。変更しました。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
    <ul class="list-group text-secondary" id="ul"></ul>
```

ブラウザが`id="ul"`の要素を読むよりも前に`index.js`が実行され、その中の`document.getElementById("ul")` の結果が`null`になっています。

`document.getElementById("ul")`の行を`add()`の中にいれるか、上記の `<script>`と `<ul>`を入れ替えるか、`index.js`の中全体を `DOMContentLoaded` イベントリスナ内で実行するように変更すると直ると思います。

Comment: <script>と<ul>の入れ替えで正常に動くようになりました。ありがとうございます‼